# Using RouteTables in WCF Hosted In Windows Service

Tags: .net, wcf

Is it possible to use a Windows Service hosted WCF application and still leverage the RouteTable objects?  I really like the routing capabilities; however, the hosted environment does not have IIS.  Thanks.

Comment: No. Routing is an ASP.NET feature - it's not present in self-hosting. What do you need it for, though?? Self-hosting already gives you pretty much all the control you want.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the routing works only inside an ASP.NET application which itself requires IIS. Actually in WCF you shouldn't be using routing. You could use [RESTful WCF services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx) where you have control over the urls and verbs.